# Two combo values into sql string

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to combine two combobox selected values in a sql string with the following code :

```
      opdragplaasnommer.CommandText = "SELECT plaasnommer FROM oesskattings 
      WHERE plaasnaam =  '" & CmbPlaasnaam.Text & "'" And aliasnaam = " '" & 
      CmbAliasnaam.Text & "'"
```

However, I think I am messing up with my quotes and double quotes. I get the following error message :

> Additional information: Conversion from string "SELECT plaasnommer
>   FROM oesskatt" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really ought to learn how to use the `String.Format` method or string interpolation.  It is far less error-prone than using the concatenation operator (`&`) over and over.  You can see the issue with your code simply by looking at the colour.  Anything in a literal `String` should be red and you can see some of yours that should be red but isn't.  Presumably it should be something like this:

```
opdragplaasnommer.CommandText = "SELECT plaasnommer FROM oesskattings WHERE plaasnaam = '" & CmbPlaasnaam.Text & "' And aliasnaam = '" & CmbAliasnaam.Text & "'"
```

Using `String.Format` would look like this:

```
opdragplaasnommer.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT plaasnommer FROM oesskattings WHERE plaasnaam = '{0}' And aliasnaam = '{1}'", CmbPlaasnaam.Text, CmbAliasnaam.Text)
```

As you can see, far less easy to mess up.  String interpolation would look like this:

```
opdragplaasnommer.CommandText = $"SELECT plaasnommer FROM oesskattings WHERE plaasnaam = '{CmbPlaasnaam.Text}' And aliasnaam = '{CmbAliasnaam.Text}'"
```

Given that this is SQL code, an even better idea would be to use parameters.  I'm not going to go into detail about that because there's information all over the place but it's something that you really need to learn.  Apart from your code being less error-prone, it will help avoid crashes due to formatting issues and, most importantly, protect you from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you. I will use the string.format in future. It is less messy.

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up with your string;

```
opdragplaasnommer.CommandText = "SELECT plaasnommer FROM oesskattings WHERE plaasnaam =  '" & CmbPlaasnaam.Text & "' And aliasnaam =  '" & CmbAliasnaam.Text & "'"
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I will use the string.format in future.

Answer (score 0):

In VB .NET string concatination is performed with & symbol. And new line requires underscore.

```
opdragplaasnommer.CommandText = "SELECT plaasnommer FROM oesskattings" & _
      " WHERE plaasnaam =  '" & CmbPlaasnaam.Text & "' And aliasnaam = '" & _
      CmbAliasnaam.Text & "'"
```

But I would suggest to use `String.Format` function in this case.

```
opdragplaasnommer.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT plaasnommer FROM oesskattings WHERE plaasnaam = '{0}' and aliasnaam = '{1}'", 
CmbPlaasnaam.Text,CmbAliasnaam.Text)
```

And again this just another way. But, to say the truth, I hate concatination for SQL queries. Better to declare SQL Parameters and assign value to them.

Comment: Actually, starting with VS2010, the underscore is (usually) optional for line continuations.  But +1 for SQL parameters recommendation.